# How to send text to a list of number via ADB Shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

We use the following command to send a text message through the ABD and phone connected to the machine. Looking to replace the number with a list of numbers. Not sure how would it be executed. Can someone please help.
Thanks.

```
adb shell am startservice -e sms_number "0123456789" -e sms_body "SMS TEXT HERE" -n
com.companyname.companyservice/com.companyname.services.SMSSendService
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in similiar situation as me. I got it working with following command.

```
 FOR /F %x IN (phonelist.txt) DO adb shell am startservice -e sms_number "%x" -e sms_body "SMS BODY HERE" -n com.companyname.companysms/com.companyname.services.SMSSendService
```

Answer (score 1):

save your list of numbers in a text file (eg: phonelist.txt), one per line. Copy the file to `/data/local/tmp`, and use a `for` loop. see below

```
adb push phonelist.txt /data/local/tmp
adb shell for x in `cat /data/local/tmp/phonelist.txt`; do 
    am startservice -e sms_number $x -e sms_body "SMS TEXT HERE" -n
    com.companyname.companyservice/com.companyname.services.SMSSendService; 
    sleep 3;done
```

Does your SMSSendService handle invoking repeatedly ? you may consider adding a delay between each sms message sent (modify the sleep time above).

Comment: Hi Ashoke,

Thanks for your help. The code seems nice. I should have mentioned I am on windows platform. Would highly appreciate if you could assist me there.

Comment: that code runs on android device, give it a try. Does not matter what your development system is.

Comment: Possibly depending on android version you can embed a newline and split on that, avoiding the file push.  For (non-SMS) example, `adb shell 'echo 12345\\n78910 | while read f ; do echo $f ; done'`

Comment: Hi guys,

Thanks a lot for the help. I got it working with following command.

FOR /F %x IN (phonelist.txt) DO adb shell am startservice -e sms_number "%x" -e sms_body "SMS BODY HERE" -n com.companyname.companysms/com.companyname.services.SMSSendService